# How to decompress a GZIP string in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, gzip

I'm receiving data daily from a third party. This data is compressed as a GZIP string (Looks like this: "0x1F8B0800000000000400E5BDED72DB489636782B8C8EE899AAE876990048909CF17...") and should decompress as XML raw.

I'm currently working off BigQuery and I have yet to find a solution to decompressing a string like this (Most solutions are for T-SQL). Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find any solution? Even I'm looking for this solution.